# Live data plotting using pyserial, matplotlib, and tkinter GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, arduino

I am currently working on a project in which I am using two potentiometers and an Arduino Uno to gather live (x,y) positioning data (one potentiometer for the x and one for the y). I am currently able to establish the serial connection with the Arduino and pull up a tkinter GUI with a figure and two buttons(one to start plotting and one to stop it), but as soon as I try to read serial data and update the figure at the same time, the serial connection appears to freeze and no longer updates the values. No errors are raised, so I'm not sure what is happening. The serial data comes in as a string of two values (x and y), separated by a space. I have realized that if I comment out the canvas.draw() line, the serial communication works just fine and updates live in the console. I have attached my relevant code below.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import pyautogui as gui
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import serial as sr
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

# ------------Global Variables ------------#
data_x = np.array([])
data_y = np.array([])

screen_width, screen_height = gui.size()
cond = False


def mapValues(num, x_or_y):
    global screen_width, screen_height
    maxValX = 1023
    maxValY = 1023
    if x_or_y == 1:
        proportion = num / maxValX
        new_val = round(screen_width * proportion)
        if new_val > screen_width:
            new_val = screen_width
    else:
        proportion = num / maxValY
        new_val = round(screen_height * proportion)
        if new_val > screen_height:
            new_val = screen_height
    if new_val < 0:
        new_val = 0
    return new_val


def plot_data():
    global cond, data_x, data_y, s
    len_line = 4
    if cond:  # to prevent continuous data logging
        data = s.readline()  # read and decode the serial data
        data = data.decode()
        try:
            coordinates = data.split()  # split the incoming str data into the x and y components
            x_val = coordinates[0]
            y_val = coordinates[1]
            # print(x_val, y_val, type(x_val))
            x_val = mapValues(int(x_val), 1)  # map the values to an arbitrary range
            y_val = mapValues(int(y_val), 2)
            print(x_val, y_val)
            # print('length of array: ', len(data_x))
            # print(data_x, '\n', data_y)
            if len(data_x) < len_line:  # keep the length of the x,y data consistently at whatever value we want
                data_x = np.append(data_x, x_val)
                data_y = np.append(data_y, 320 - y_val)
            else:  # shift all the values back in the list and add the new one to the end
                data_x[0:len_line-1] = data_x[1:len_line]
                data_x[len_line-1] = x_val
                data_y[0:len_line-1] = data_y[1:len_line]
                data_y[len_line-1] = y_val

            # update the x and y data of the line
            line1.set_xdata(data_x)
            line1.set_ydata(data_y)
            print('Line data: ', line1.get_xydata())

            # update the canvas
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.flush_events()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    root.after(1, plot_data)


def start_plot():
    global s, cond
    s.reset_input_buffer()
    cond = True


def stop_plot():
    global cond, s
    cond = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting...')

    # ----------main GUI code --------------------#
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Real Time Motus Hand')
    root.configure(background='black')
    app_width = 1200
    app_height = 800
    x_offset = (screen_width - app_width) / 2
    y_offset = (screen_height - app_height) / 2
    root.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x_offset)}+{int(y_offset)}')

    # ---------- create plot object on figure ----------#
    fig = Figure()
    # customize parameters
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
    ax.set_xlim(0, screen_width)
    ax.set_ylim(0, screen_height)
    #  create line object to control data
    line1 = ax.plot([], [])[0]
    #  define figure height and width and placement
    plot_width = 800
    plot_height = 600
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=(app_width - plot_width) / 2, y=(app_height - plot_height) / 2,
                                 width=plot_width, height=plot_height)
    canvas.draw()

    # ----------create start and stop buttons -------------
    start = tk.Button(root, text='start drawing', font=('calbiri', 12), command=lambda: start_plot())
    start.place(x=100, y=app_height - 50)

    stop = tk.Button(root, text='stop drawing', font=('calbiri', 12), command=lambda: stop_plot())
    stop.place(x=300, y=app_height - 50)

    # --------start serial communication ---------
    s = sr.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem142201', 9600)
    s.reset_input_buffer()

    root.after(1, plot_data)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue of threading. Ran into something similar awhile ago when using a TKinter ui -- consider creating a 'global' class to store info that's being presented within the Tkinter frame, and instantiate a thread to update those values rather than trying to use the main thread/process to do several things at once, especially updating visual elements. If that's an always-updating or at least frequently-updating event, it'll lock up your main process trying to write to the UI rather than continuing the process, so creating a class to store data and having a thread responsible for doing so can offload some of the burden from your main processing thread as one thread, even the main thread, can only do one thing at a time.

Just re-read your description and based on the behavior you observe when commenting out the canvas draw I'm feeling moreso confident that this is a threading issue...

If examples are needed let me know and I'll see what I can do

Also, it seems that you're involved with some sort of physics or engineering project - good luck!

--- Threading example(s):
The documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html
But I find the language convoluted, so I'll skip to the basics:

```
import threading
thread = threading.Thread(target=FUNCTION,args=[Parameter1,Parameter2,...,ParameterN])
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

There's a few important parts here, mainly 1) FUNCTION is some function that you have defined, in this case I would imagine you could write a function that collects the current data and sets the value to the tkinter ui; just give the name of the function like I've got it there, don't add your parathensis or arguments, because number two is 2) args = [] is a list of all your variables within the function, important that you do this as a list or threading gets confused 3) then you instantiate the operation with thread.start(), but you also have the option of doing a thread.join() which will halt your program from continuing until the thread has finished, which might not be what you're looking for. Totally optional.

I would recommend playing around with this as a tool to see how it fits best, and again, I recommend making some generic class (I ussually call it MyGlobals or some variation) to store data/values, because the thread will not be able to access global variables unless explicitly stated within your function. Additionally, if you have several threads for several different operations there's nothing stopping you from making them into a list and then using iteration to start/join all of them consecutively. Many different routes, but alas this is your adventure. Go forth and have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have never really worked with threading, so some examples would be super useful! I had a suspicion that it could be a threading issue from other posts I have read, but I wasn't sure how to approach it.

Comment: @JCrypp I've added some explanation of how threading works, let me know if there's anything else I can do to help